# immer.js merge nested object

Tags: reactjs, immer.js

I'd like to merge nested object using immer.js

It's always been hard to merge two nested object.
I wonder if the following is possible with any library..

```
state = {
  lv1_1: {
    lv2_1: {
      lv3_1: 'foo1',
      lv3_2: 'foo2',
    },
    lv2_2: {
      lv3_2: 'foo2'
    }
  },
  lv1_2: {
    lv2_1: 'foo'
  }
}



lv1_1 = {
  lv2_1: {
    lv3_1: 'bar'
  }
}
```

merge lv1_1 with state, I want the following output.

```
state = {
  lv1_1: {
    lv2_1: {
      lv3_1: 'bar',
      lv3_2: 'foo2',
    },
    lv2_2: {
      lv3_2: 'foo2'
    }
  },
  lv1_2: {
    lv2_1: 'foo'
  }

}
```

I tried immerse.js but the following code 
`draft.lv1_1 = {...draft.lv1_1, ...lv1_1}` seems to give

```
state = {
  lv1_1: {
    lv2_1: {
      lv3_1: 'bar'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you know the shape of the object you want to merge? can you do `toMerge.lv1_1.lv2_1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wonder if the following is possible with any library..

You can try [`lodash.merge`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#merge):

```
const a = {
  lv1_1: {
    lv2_1: {
      lv3_1: 'foo1',
      lv3_2: 'foo2'
    },
    lv2_2: {
      lv3_2: 'foo2'
    }
  },
  lv1_2: {
    lv2_1: 'foo'
  }
};

const b = {
  lv1_1: {
    lv2_1: {
      lv3_1: 'bar'
    }
  }
};
console.log(_.merge(a, b));
```

Comment: Hmmm, I wonder if `lodash.merge` would be ok when working on a `draft` (in immerjs). I mean when doing something like `draft.list[index] = merge(draft.list[index], oneOrTwoUpdatedAttributes)`.

Comment: @GregVenech is it - have you tried?

Comment: I haven't but I don't think it would work unless you forced it to create a new object by passing an empty one as the first parameter. We're using it in a legacy part of an app and saw that it doesn't create a new object out of the box so I think the code I shared above might throw an error (from immer).

Comment: Be careful using lodash merge(). It will merge not just nested objects but also nested arrays. Depending on your use case this may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

try it:

```
import produce, { current } from 'immer'
import _ from 'lodash'

produce(a, (draft) => {
  _.merge(current(draft), b)
})
```

Comment: Please elaborate why this solves the question...

Comment: why do you introduce the current function?

Answer (score 0):

It does work because what `lodash.merge()` does (which is mutating the object) it's exactly what `immer` is designed to protect. `immer` does this through a proxied object. Learn more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

In that line of thought, when you pass a draft to `_.merge()` the function will mutate the draft, which `immer` is expecting you to do.
@吴哲卿's answer tried to finalize the object (without freezing it) with `current`, the `current()` is exported by immer, and it's mostly used for debugging because when you try to `console.log()` a proxied object it prints as the proxy it is and it can be very hard to read. But using current within `immer`'s recipe especially for this use case **it's incorrect** instead of providing the proxied draft to `immer`'s `produce`, you give it a finalized object which is then returned and replaces the whole thing, this makes `immer` incapable of tracking changes on the object you're trying to protect.
Be mindful that you either return a new object that you create or modify the draft's properties (but not both).
[image: examples of explanation in a playground]